# Automapper mapping List member how to use destination if source empty

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-8

I am mapping below classes using Automapper

```
public class InfoDto
{
    public List<string> Names { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
    public List<string> Names { get; set; }
}
```

I want to preserve `destination Names` value if `source Names` is null or empty. I tried configuring Mapper as below, but it seem to be clearing `destination Names` before mapping.

```
    CreateMap<InfoDto, Info>()
        .ForMember(d => d.Names,
            opt => opt.MapFrom(
                (src, dest) =>
                    src.Names != null && src.Names.Any() ? src.Names : dest.Names));

var infoDto = new InfoDto{ Names = new List<string>{"Test1", "Test2"}}; 
var info = Mappert.Map<Info>(infoDto);

var infoDto1 = new InfoDto{ Names = null}; 
Mapper.Map<InfoDto, Info>(infoDto1, info); 
// info.Names should be list with 2 values
```

Is there a way I can retrieve/preserve `destination Names` value and use it if `source Names` is empty?

Comment: When mapping to an existing collection, the destination collection is cleared first. If this is not what you want, take a look at AutoMapper.Collection.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if there might be another solution but this one I've just tested and works.

I often find it usefull to process the more complex mappings in a `Aftermap` method. It gives you more freedom to add some extra complexity. In this case you could create a Map like this:

```
        CreateMap<InfoDto, Info>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Names, opt => opt.Ignore())
            // here you can map other properties just regularly if you want
            .AfterMap(mapNames);
```

You ignore the properties you want to map in the `Aftermap` method.
In your case the `Aftermap` would look something like this:

```
private void mapNames(InfoDto source, Info destination)
    {
        if (source.Names != null && source.Names.Any())
        {
            destination.Names = source.Names;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I did try AfterMap before. Problem is destination.Names value is reset and is null in AfterMap().

Comment: Dit you add the line: `.ForMember(d => d.Names, opt => opt.Ignore())`

Comment: Yes. I am using AutoMapper 8.1.0

Comment: Then I might not understand your problem correctly. This works perfect when I test. `destination.Names` is being set by the `source.Names` but only when source has an value. Or you sure the mapping is registered and not some sort of default mapping is applied?

Comment: Yes, `destination.Names` is being set by the `source.Names` when source has an value. But when `source.Names` has no value, I want `destination.Names` to retain its previous value.